# increment multiple div ids by 1 onclick()

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a `<div>` with `textbox` "`4 radiobuttons(single group)`" and a "`remove button`". 
there is a button on top saying "ADD DIV". When i click on ADD DIV, it adds a new  div with "textbox" "4 radiobuttons(single group)" and a "remove button".

Using Javascript, created a counter to increment `textbox` ID's. Now i want to increase the radio button group ID too.

Here is the crappy pen:
 http://codepen.io/b0y/pen/YwGqWr

Comment: Please edit your post to include the most relevant code here. You can use the `{}` button in the post editor (shortcut, `Ctlr+K`) to format them as [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Codepens and similar examples are definitely welcome, but the question should still be answerable without an outside reference.

Comment: Actually the code is too big to post here, so i am using external link.

Comment: can you please let know which id you want to modify. because from dom I ma seeing the fieldset also have different id

Comment: thanks @user2181397 . the problem got solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. Add a data-id attribute to your field sets (This is not needed if you just want to get the next ID for your radio button group):

   `<fieldset id="radio0" name="radioList" data-fieldset-id="0">`

2.Then in your click event handler, fetch the fieldset with highest fieldset data id value:

```
function getNextFieldSetCount() {

        var fieldsetCount = $('fieldset[data-fieldset-id]').length + 1;

        return fieldsetCount;

    }
```

3.If you want to increment the value of existing radio button groups as well:

```
$('fieldset[data-fieldset-id]').each(function(index, element)) {
   $(this).attr('id', 'radio'+ parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'))+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just give a unique id to elements u can use time for element id

```
var n = new Date().getTime();
```